# I expect the result to be a dictionary but it is accessed like a property... why?

Tags: json, swift

I have this JSON coming from a server...

```
{
  "cars": [
    {
      "name": "Ferrari",
      "price": "100"
    },
    {
      "name": "Lamborghini",
      "price": "200"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ford Pinto",
      "price": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

This JSON is a dictionary called `cars` that contains an array of cars, right?

Then I have this struct...

```
struct Cars: Codable {
    let cars: [Car]
}


struct Car: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let price: String
}
```

and I decode the JSON using this:

```
let (data, _) = try await urlSession.data(from: url)
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Cars.self, from: data)
let listOfCars = result.cars
```

This is something I don't understand.

in `result.cars`, `cars` is a property of `result` that was declared as an array in the struct `Cars`. Not a dictionary.

I was expecting to access it using `result["cars"]`.

Why is that?

Comment: If we annotate result as `let result: Cars` then it becomes more clear. The `result` is not a dictionary, is a struct of type `Cars`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code here...

```
let (data, _) = try await urlSession.data(from: url)
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Cars.self, from: data)
let listOfCars = result.cars
```

`result` is an instance of the Struct `Cars`. Your set up code has told Swift how to translate from a JSON dictionary into your own Struct.

So everything inside of `result` is accessed just like how you would access it in the following...

```
let result = Cars(cars: [
  Car(name: "Ford", price: "£10,000")
])

print(result.cars)
```

The only difference is how you are creating it. Instead of using the init method like this you are using a JSON decode to decode some JSON into your custom type.

Comment: I see, thanks. Amazing explanation.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments and answers, it takes a result type according to your decode strategy. In your code `result type is Cars` not a `dictionary`. So you access the properties with using `result.cars`

If you want something as dictionary instead, you need to decode it like

```
let result = try decode.decode([String : [Car]].self, from: data)
```

Now you can access them like a dictionar

```
print(result["cars"]?.first?.name) // Optional("Ferrari")
```

Comment: ahhh, I see it now. Swift if doing some magic here and manipulating the original JSON. But in the original JSON what is coming is a dictionary, right?

Comment: Yeah it is @Duck